# Issue in updating the listview from a listener in another class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am developing a chat application using XMPP. I have a chat listener initialized  in my LoginActivity and from that I want to a listview in my ChatActivity from that listener. ie, When an incoming message is received, I need to update the ListView in ChatActivity.

I am using the following code to update the ListView from listener class.

```
ChatActivity chatActivity = new ChatActivity();
chatActivity.new GetChatsfromListener().execute();
```

I am trying to call an AsycTask in the ChatActivity using the above code.

But I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

in the following line in postExcecute() method of the AsyncTask.

```
adapter = new ChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this,R.layout.item_chat, chatList);
```

Please help to solve this

Comment: Where do you call `execute()`?

Comment: @Fox ...in the listener class. I am calling the listener class from LoginActivity

Comment: So I suppose you need to show more code. These four lines of code do not say anything.